# before I factory reset my galany j3

Tags: backup, factory-reset, photos, locked-out, file-management

my daughter has locked herself out of her phone. so before I factory reset her galaxy j3 luna. she's is hoping there's a way I could hook up the phone to a cpu and save her pics & other files?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! As you already found the `locked-out` tag: did you take a look at [its tag wiki](/tags/locked-out/info)? As this is a somehow freequent question, we've set up some first aid there.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is locked and you are not able to open it in any other way, (check the lockscreen, sometimes email is an option), then the device content is gone.

You could try this though:

- Take a look into Google photos, sometimes they are backed up there, just search Google photos on your PC.
- They could be in Google drive too.

Comment: I did try this method. and yes she was able to recovery some. but since she surpassed allowed data, there are many she is still missing. but that where saved to internal memory.

Comment: I don't know any other method. Unless you know how to bypass your daughter's cofe.

Comment: I don't but appreciate your help. thank you.